# Why can't I overwrite my old generator in my double itertion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, generator

I've tried to solve a Chinese puzzle with a function as described [here](https://github.com/zhiwehu/Python-programming-exercises/blob/master/100%2B%20Python%20challenging%20programming%20exercises.txt) (it's the last exercise). My code contains the description of the problem so you can just look at that. Anyways, I found out, that when I do a double iteration using two generators, the second for-loop exhausts the second generator and I can't restart it by deleting it and resetting it, because of the bare-bones nature of generators. You can't check if a generator is exhausted without pushing it one step further in it's iteration and then reset it to it's prior position by doing something like:

```py
generator1 = (bla1 for bla1 in Bla1)
generator2 = (bla2 for bla2 in Bla2)

for bla1 in generator1:
    for bla2 in generator2:
        if next(generator) == StopIteration:
            generator2 = (bla2 for bla2 in Bla2)
```

I know, that I have to reinitialize a generator by creating it again, but it looks like I can't put my generator in a variable and do a successful double iteration. The generators must apparently be specified in the "for i in..." line to be dynamically created each time a loop is entered. My problem is, that I'd like to create a generator on one line, put it in a variable and then reset it at will so I can do my double iteration, since some generators I use are very long.

```py
'''
Question:

Write a program to solve a classic ancient Chinese puzzle: 
We count 35 heads and 94 legs among the chickens and rabbits in a farm.
How many rabbits and how many chickens do we have?

Strategy: Double iteration. Keep the number of one animal constant and
add more of the other until you either hit 94 legs or overshoot.
'''


def Chinese_puzzle(heads,legs):

    if legs%2 != 0:
        return 'There are no crippled animals on this farm.'

    for rabbits, r_legs in enumerate((leg*4 for leg in range(round(legs/4)))):
        for chickens, c_legs in enumerate((leg*2 for leg in range(round(legs/2)))):
            leggs = r_legs+c_legs
            hedds = rabbits+chickens
            if leggs == legs and hedds == heads:
                return {'Chickens':chickens,'Rabbits':rabbits}
            elif leggs > legs or hedds > heads:
                break

    return 'No permutation of rabbits and chickens exists for this number of legs and heads'


print(Chinese_puzzle(35,94))
```

Can I somehow get rid of these huge generators inside my for loop for more readability?

```py
enumerate((leg*4 for leg in range(round(legs/4))))
```

As I said, doing

```py
Rabbits = enumerate((leg*4 for leg in range(round(legs/4))))
```

doesn't work for double iterations.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer your question, but your double iteration is an extremely inefficient solution to this problem.  If you loop over the possible quantity of one animal, there are only two quantities of the other animal that are even conceivable solutions: the one that gets the number of heads right, and the one that gets the number of legs right.  If those two number are the same, and valid (not negative), that's your solution without needing an inner loop at all.

Comment: Yeah I know it's a brute force solution :D Didn't really give it much thought since I did it out of boredom. Ran into an unexpected problem along the way though.

Comment: "`if next(generator) == StopIteration` well, this just doesn't work the way you seem to expect. `next` does not *return* `StopIteration`, it *raises* it, so you'd have to use exception handling, but this approach is pretty broken to begin with, because using `next` inside the loop is problematic to say the least. What you *really* want to do is: "Can I somehow get rid of these huge generators inside my for loop for more readability?". well, in that case, **use functions** which is almost always the answer to "how can I make my code more organized and readable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is how you can remake the inner generator without putting the calls to create it in the same line as the `for` loop. I think the easiest way is to simply move the line defining `generator2` into the outer loop:

```
generator1 = whatever()  # this could be a long generator expression
for i in generator1:
    generator2 = whatever2()
    for j in generator2:
        ...
```

Your current code was not working for a large number of reasons. Among them, `next` doesn't `return` a `StopIteration`, it raises one as an exception. But there was no reason to be trying to call `next` inside the inner loop anyway, you just need to recreate the exhausted generator on each iteration of the outer loop.

But as jasonharper commented, you don't actually need two nested loops for this problem. First lets try with just one loop. All you need to do is calculate the number of chickens and chicken legs you'd need to make the total counts work for a given number of rabbits (as you loop over that number). Then check if the legs are double the heads. If so, you've found your solution.

```
for rabbits in range(heads+1):
    r_legs = rabbits * 4
    chickens = heads - rabbits
    c_legs = legs - r_legs
    if c_legs == chickens * 2:
        return {"Rabbits": rabbits, "Chickens": chickens}
```

But you can take it one step further and do without the outer loop too. First assume that all the heads belong to chickens. Each chicken has a pair of legs. We can easily calculate how many extra pairs of legs were counted. For every extra pair, one of the heads belongs to a rabbit instead of a chicken.

```
def Chinese_puzzle(heads,legs):
    rabbits = legs // 2 - heads
    chickens = heads - rabbits
    return {"Rabbits": rabbits, "Chickens": chickens}
```

I'm not doing any sanity checking here, but you probably only need to check for odd numbers of legs, or negative counts of chickens or rabbits. I suggest raising an exception in those cases, rather than returning an error message string.

Answer (score 1):

`for bla2 in generator2:` only evaluates the variable once, when the iteration starts. The iterator is held in an internal temporary, it doesn't re-evaluate the variable each time.

You can change that to:

```
while True:
    try:
        bla2 = next(generator2)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This is equivalent to the `for` loop, except that it evaluates the variable each time.

Comment: Huh...thanks. I thought I had tried that, but apparently I wasn't paying enough attention to the output/errors of the program.

Comment: This **will not work**. `next` does *not return `StopIteration`, well, it *could* but that is not how it typically works.

Comment: Oh yeah, now I remember. I didn't bother to find out the difference between a raise and a return. I'm guessing a jerry-rig that essentially works this way is not exactly "pythonic"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I've changed it to use `try/except` to detect `StopIteration`